# Spring Integration Multiple Endpoints

Tags: spring-integration

Currently i am working on a Spring Integration application which has a following scenario.

1. There is a Transformer which transforms incoming message in to a particular object type
2. Once the transformation is done, we need to write it to a log file and to a database table and then finally send to a JMS outbound adapter.

I was reading the Spring Integration reference and found out there are two ways we can approach this scenario.

1. Introduce a pub-sub channel as the output channel of the above mentioned transformer and have File-outbound, DB-outbound and JMS-outbound as the subscribers.
2. Introduce a Recipient List Router just after the transformer and specify the File-outbound, DB-outbound and JMS-outbound as the recipients.

When it comes to Enterprise Integration Patterns what is the best way to handle this scenario? Any new suggestions and improvements are welcome

Thanks,
Keth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "best way" - both solutions are equivalent and there is little difference at runtime. So it's your preference; I generally use pub/sub for the simple case and an RLR if the recipients are conditional (with selectors).